# Regular expressions to exclude a specific format from a list of strings

Tags: python, regex

I started recently working with regular expressions and they are not very clear to me at the moment.

I have a list of strings:

```
l = ['1P', '2.2', '1.2MP', '1.2P', '1.2.3', '1.2.3 P', '4.5.6']
```

How can i exclude all the strings that contains this format : x.y.z?

So the list will look like this :

```
l = ['1P', '2.2', '1.2MP', '1.2P']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
pattern = "\d+\.\d+\.\d+"  # 3 digits separated by two dots, each one with 1 or more digit
l = ['1P', '2.2', '1.2MP', '1.2P', '1.2.3', '1.2.3 P', '4.5.6']
matched = [item for item in l if not re.search(pattern, item)]
# matched = ['1P', '2.2', '1.2MP', '1.2P']
```

You can see [`re.serach()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) and how it matches the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my regex.

`^(?!(?:.+?[.]){2}).*$`

`^(?!(?:.+?[.]{2})` ->  This is a negative lookahead. This part ensures that string are not in `x.y.z` format.

`.*`  -> If the above  is  true then match  entire string.

[Demo link](https://regex101.com/r/S900Ou/1).